# Simulate Orbital Motion around a body in Matlab

Tags: matlab, simulation, gravity, satellite

Im working on a very simple program to simulate the orbital movement of a body around another body, just like a satellite around earth. I have followed the guidelines and equations available in books and internet but the object doesn't seem to be orbiting at all. Kindly help me if someone can. Thanks in advance. The code is below

```
v0=80;
theta=45*pi/180;

vx(1)=v0*cos(theta);
vy(1)=v0*sin(theta);
px(1)=0;
py(1)=0;

mass=100; %kg
cmass=400; % mass of the body at 400,500
    ax=0;
%
g=9.8 ;%m/s^2
ay=-g;

p2x=400; % x co-ordinate of the stationary body
p2y=500; % y co-ordinate of the stationary body

G=6.674*10^-11; % the Gravitational Constant
figure(1)
plotsize=800;
i=1;
dt=.1;
t=0;
while(t<20)

%a2x=a2x-0.10;
%a2y=a2y+0.50;
r=sqrt((p2x-px(i))^2+(p2y-py(i))^2); % distance between the two bodies
F=((G*mass*cmass)/r^2);   % force by formula f=(G*m1*m2)/r^2
a=-(1/cmass^2)*F;    % acceleraion  a=1/m1^2*F

vx(i+1)=vx(i)+(ax)*dt;
vy(i+1)=vy(i)+(ay)*dt;

px(i+1)=px(i)+vx(i)*dt;
py(i+1)=py(i)+vy(i)*dt;

hold off
plot(px(i+1),py(i+1),'o','MarkerSize',15)

hold on
plot(px,py,'r')
plot(p2x,p2y);
axis([0 plotsize 0 plotsize])
pause(.1) %pause for graphics
i=i+1;
t=t+dt;
```

end

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717775/animate-text-in-matlab

Comment: i have seen this solution Sir. The main problem is that my mass1 is not currently in the gravitational pull of the mass2, it is moving, when it gets near, the pull gets stronger and the mass2 will attract mass 1.

Comment: There is some mixed up physics going here. Have you munged two scripts together? Your weights are quite small, so gravitational attraction is going to be weak. Then, in addition, you have placed the whole scene inside an Earth-live gravity, and "fired" the smaller particle. The plot is reasonably accurately showing what would happen if you shot something the size of a human (100kg) from the ground on Earth into the air at approx  180 miles per hour towards something the size of a small car (400kg), ignoring air resistance. Basically, very little difference from any projectile.

Answer (score 0):

Im fairly certain that your logic is off. You want to iterate time t, n number of times in steps of dt, and after time has reached 20 units (years?) stop. During the iterates where t<20, you want to appropriately adjust your parameters with respect to time. So I think you should use a for loop and nest your while conditional in the for loop to check to see if t is indeed less than 20. In other words, for i = 1:20, while t<20 do stuff, otherwise stop doing stuff!