# RBG image as texture for a 3D cube using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization, texture-mapping

I want to plot a 3D cube using matplotlib, and map an arbitary RGB image (jpg or png) as a texture to each side of the cube.  There is a good example [here using matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31831638/assigning-a-2d-image-for-every-face-of-a-3d-cube-matlab).

[image]

I just wonder how to do it using Python/matplotlib, possibly starting from [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33540109/plot-surfaces-on-a-cube).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out myself and the following is the code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.image as image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

C = image.imread('d:/timg.png')

xp, yp, __ = C.shape

x = np.arange(0, xp, 1)
y = np.arange(0, yp, 1)
Y, X = np.meshgrid(y, x)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,9))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.dist=6.2
ax.view_init(elev=38, azim=-45)

ax.plot_surface(X, Y, X-X+yp, facecolors=C,
                rstride=2, cstride=2,
                antialiased=True, shade=False)

ax.plot_surface(X, X-X, Y, facecolors=np.fliplr(C.transpose((1,0,2))),
                rstride=2, cstride=2,
                antialiased=True, shade=False)

ax.plot_surface(X-X+xp, X, Y, facecolors=np.fliplr(C.transpose((1,0,2))),
                rstride=2, cstride=2,
                antialiased=True, shade=False)
```

The resulting image is:

[3D texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LooHr.png)

Changing the stride to 1 will get more detail of the png image, but it seems that it is not a very efficient way, especially when the image size is very large.